# CQL3 select succeeds for some keys, but fails for others

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I have a pretty simple CQL3 table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_team_scores (
username text,
team_slug text,
score double,
PRIMARY KEY (username, team_slug)
) WITH
comment='' AND
caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
replicate_on_write='true' AND
compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' AND
compression_parameters:sstable_compression='SnappyCompressor';
```

I can run queries like:

```
select * from user_team_scores where username='paulingalls';
```

and it succeeds for some usernames, but fails for others with a timeout.

I'm running a 3 node cluster, and on the node I assume has the token range for the username that fails I see the following stack trace in the logs:

```
ERROR [ReadStage:66211] 2013-01-03 00:11:26,169 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 135) Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:66211,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: DecoratedKey(82585475460624048733030438888619591812, 001373616e2d6672616e636973636f2d343965727300000573636f726500) != DecoratedKey(45868142482903708675972202481337602533, 7061756c696e67616c6c73) in /mnt/datadrive/lib/cassandra/fanzo/user_team_scores/fanzo-user_team_scores-hf-1-Data.db
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.<init>(SSTableSliceIterator.java:60)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(SliceQueryFilter.java:67)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(QueryFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectAllData(CollationController.java:256)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:64)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1345)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1207)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1142)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.getRow(Table.java:378)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.SliceFromReadCommand.getRow(SliceFromReadCommand.java:69)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadVerbHandler.doVerb(ReadVerbHandler.java:51)
at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Googling around I saw some mention of potential issues with caching, so here is the log for the the cache setup on DB startup.

```
 INFO [main] 2012-12-01 04:07:53,190 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 124) Loading settings from file:/home/fanzo/apache-cassandra-1.1.6/conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO [main] 2012-12-01 04:07:53,398 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 183) DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO [main] 2012-12-01 04:07:53,756 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 249) Global memtable threshold is enabled at 676MB
 INFO [main] 2012-12-01 04:07:54,335 CacheService.java (line 96) Initializing key cache with capacity of 100 MBs.
 INFO [main] 2012-12-01 04:07:54,352 CacheService.java (line 107) Scheduling key cache save to each 14400 seconds (going to save all keys).
 INFO [main] 2012-12-01 04:07:54,354 CacheService.java (line 121) Initializing row cache with capacity of 0 MBs and provider org.apache.cassandra.cache.SerializingCacheProvider
 INFO [main] 2012-12-01 04:07:54,360 CacheService.java (line 133) Scheduling row cache save to each 0 seconds (going to save all keys).
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to fix this, or if I'm hosed....

Thanks!

Paul

Answer (score 3):

Well, not sure what the cause was for the problem, but running

```
nodetool invalidatekeycache
nodetool invalidaterowcache
```

made the problem go away.  I'm guessing there is a bug somewhere in the caching code.

Hopefully this will help others...

Comment: that must be written in big letters on their website right on the frontpage =( thanks Paul that really helped!

Answer (score 3):

It's https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4687 and not fixed as of 1.2.0